# C# Asp.Net MVC Core Identity - Migration is ignoring new columns in ASPNETUsers table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I have a fresh SQL Server database, with no tables in it, hosted in Azure.

I have an `ApplicationUser` entity, that inherits from `IdentityUser`:

[image: DB Model]

I am running the following commands in the terminal in Visual Studio:

```
dotnet ef migrations add "CreateProdAuthDatabase"
dotnet ef database update
```

The migration succeeds, but when I view the snapshot file, the new columns in `ApplicationUser`, are not in the snapshot and have been ignored.

... therefore when I attempt to seed the database with new data, I get the following SQLException:

[image: screenshot of error]

... I don't understand what's happening, and why the new entity fields are being ignored when I run the migration?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this, whereby I had forgotten to update the IdentitySchema file with the new fields.

I now have a new error, for which I've posted a separate question...